# Javascript : Right way to display the result of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I've got an array to define my variables :

```
const nbActions = 13;
const sdgValues = ['1','2', '5', '6', '3','0','2','0','0','6','0','0','0','1','0','0','0'];

let sdg = [];
for (let i = 0; i < sdgValues.length; ++i) {
    sdg[i] = (sdgValues[i] / nbActions * 100).toPrecision(4);       
}
```

But now, I want to display this value on dataSDGs with a loop without define all sdg[x] one by bone:

```
const dataSDGs = {
   data: [
            sdg['0'],
            sdg['1'],
            sdg['2'],
            sdg['3'],
            ...
    ]
}
```

My goal is to get this value to make a chart with chart.js

Comment: `const dataSDGs = { data: sdg };` ?

Comment: Or `{ data: sdg.slice() }` to clone

Comment: It's not working, I get no data :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should do it, no need for a loop:

```js
const nbActions = 13;
const sdgValues = ['1','2', '5', '6', '3','0','2','0','0','6','0','0','0','1','0','0','0'];

const dataSDGs = {
  data: sdgValues.map(
    sdg=>(sdg / nbActions * 100).toPrecision(4)
  )
}


console.log(
  dataSDGs  
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    const nbActions = 13;
const sdgValues = ['1','2', '5', '6', '3','0','2','0','0','6','0','0','0','1','0','0','0'];


let sdg =sdgValues.map((item)=>{
    return (item / nbActions * 100).toPrecision(4);   
})

var dataSDGs = {};
dataSDGs.data = sdg;
console.log(dataSDGs);
```